# How to find a specific text in files with specific extension?

Tags: command-line, search, find, grep

Let's say I'm searching for all files with `.log` extension that contain the text of `abc`.

When searching for files with any extension would look like
(Ref.: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16140/38353 )

```
find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "abc"
```

How could we modify this so that it will search only for files with `.log` extension?

I'll be more than happy if you show a better command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Add `-iname "*.log"` after `/` to your `find` command. Refer to man page for more info

**A more detailed answer**

The task at hand is the following:

1. List files that match pattern `*.log`
2. Execute `grep` per each file to find whether or not it contains a specific string.
3. List the filename that has a match on the `stdout`

The example of how that can be accomplished can be seen bellow:

```
$ find /var/log -iname "*.log" -exec grep -l 'wlan' {} \+
```

Essentially there's 3 things at play:

- `find` does the job of finding files AND calling `grep` per list of filenames in the `-exec ...{} \+`  structure, where `{}` will be substituted with all the filenames found.
- `-iname "*.log"` can provide case-insensetive matching of the filenames
- `-exec . . .{} \+` calls the low-level `execve` function that will spawn `grep -l` with the list of all the files found in front of it ( in the place of `{}` ).
- The `\+` is the option that specifies for `execve` to pack as any files as possible in front of `grep` (the limit is set by `ARG_MAX` variable, is specific to `exec`, and for Ubuntu is at `2097152` as can be shown by `getconf ARG_MAX` command ). Once the limit is reached, `exec` will repeat the call to `grep` with more files packed as arguments. The `\` is necessary to ensure `+` is interpreted as argument to `find` and not as another shell command.
- the `-l` option or grep shows files with matched string. `-L` would match files without the string.

Comment: Thanks, Serg. The command shows the contents of the files are being searched. Is there a way not to show the content? Because I only need the list of file

Comment: @oscar yes, the -l flag for grep will do that. I am on mobile so it's hard to post complete answer. I'll edit as soon as I'm home